# ¿Cómo llamar un archivo html?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Si así se usa un *link* para incluir “llamar” un archivo *css*, entonces **¿Cuál sería la etiqueta para incluir un archivo html?**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
```

Comment: No veo la necesidad, pero si quieres reutilizar un fragmento de codigo html puedes escribirlo en php y de este modo solo incluirlo en diferentes archivos php

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es importante siempre tratar de realizar pregunta en base a [ask], de esta forma obtendrás la ayuda deseada de una forma más rápida, asegura agregar detalles e información que permitan a los miembros de la comunidad ayudarte de una mejor forma,saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes cargarlo con 'javascript' o en este caso como en el ejemplo que te dejo aquí con j'query'. Dependerá de las necesidades de tu código.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('AQUI LLAMAS A DONDE QUIERAS INCLUIR EL CÓDIGO HTML').load('AQUIARCHIVOHTML.html');
});
```

Es decir:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id').load('archivo.html');
});
```

En cualquier caso si quieres realizar está acción de manera recurrente creo que será mejor que montes tu site con frameworks o gestores cómo Angular, Vue o React, por ejemplo, que te permitirán generar el contenido y controlar su inserción en código de manera más eficiente.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="nombredepagina.html">mi pagina</a>
```

Si quieres que la pagina se abra en otra pestaña hazlo de esta manera:

```
<a href="nombredepagina.html" target="_blank">mi pagina</a>
```

Comment: Con eso únicamente estás cambiando de página, creo que el OP se refiere a cómo incluirla dentro de otro HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Si deseas ver la página en cuestión, podrías utilizar `iframe`, con el cual puedes incluir una página en otra.

Ejemplo:

```html
<iframe id="FrameExample"
    title="Example"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="https://react-bootstrap.github.io">
</iframe>
```

Como verás, accede a la página de React desde el ejemplo.

Comment: Con las etiquetas que ha puesto OP, ésta es la respuesta más acertada de momento.

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo que quieres es traer parte de un html en sobre otro html, en dado caso esta seria la respuesta. De todos modos checa la palabra 'include' en el manual de php https://www.php.net/

```
<?php
 include 'ruta/nombrearchivo.html';
?>
```

Comment: Y si el OP no utiliza o no conoce sobre PHP?

Comment: No agrego mas código y su pregunta solo se basa en como agregar, si busca algo mas especifico, su pregunta debiera ser mas clara y con mas código, de otro modo solo contesto a lo que se pide

Comment: Entonces no deberías responder preguntas mal planteadas, es mejor dar respuestas que no necesiten aclaración por parte del autor. No todas las preguntas necesitan ser contestadas. Por favor visita: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Lo que más sorprende es que le den dos votos positivos a una respuesta que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.

Answer (score -3):

Los archivos HTML no son llamados, sino que los enlaces te llevan a otro archivo usando la etiqueta de enlaces. También se pueden incluir partes dentro de otro con con la etiqueta iframe. Los archivos HTML no pueden ser llamados porque no son programas, son un tipo de documentos.

Saludos.